# Jquery OnChange Won't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I am trying to trigger an onchange on a select box, to show the value that has been selected as an alert.

My current select box code is as follows:

```
<span class="location select-box">
  <input class="value-holder" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Select a Location">
<div class="advanced-select-button">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<ul class="select-clone custom-list">
  <li data-value="1">Advertising</li>
  <li data-value="2">Airport</li>
  <li data-value="3">Cars</li>
  <li data-value="4">Education</li>
  <li data-value="5">Entertainment</li>
  <li data-value="6">Garden</li>
  <li data-value="2">Airport</li>
  <li data-value="3">Cars</li>
  <li data-value="4">Education</li>
  <li data-value="5">Entertainment</li>
  <li data-value="6">Garden</li>
  <li data-value="2">Airport</li>
  <li data-value="3">Cars</li>
</ul>

<select name="Select_Location" data-placeholder="Select a Location">
   <option>Select Category</option>
          <option value="1">Advertising</option>
          <option value="2">Airport</option>
          <option value="3">Cars</option>
          <option value="4">Education</option>
          <option value="5">Entertainment</option>
          <option value="6">Garden</option>
          <option value="2">Airport</option>
          <option value="3">Cars</option>
          <option value="4">Education</option>
          <option value="5">Entertainment</option>
          <option value="6">Garden</option>
          <option value="2">Airport</option>
          <option value="3">Cars</option>
        </select>
      </span>
```

My current jquery script is as follows:

```
<script>
    $('select').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
    })
</script>
```

I can't see where I am going wrong, or what I am doing wrong here. The above Jquery code is just one of many iterations I've tried without success.

If someone can figure this out for me - I would be eternally grateful.

Thanks in advance.

p.s - if you would like to see an example - I can provide a URL.

Comment: wrap your code in document-ready handler

Comment: how do i do that Satpal? Any clues with code examples woudl help - I am using a ready made template hence the confusion

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { // your change handler});

Comment: Please note: you do not strictly need a *DOM ready handler, if your script is included at the end of `body`. It just needs to run after the DOM element exists (which is what the DOM ready handler enforces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="location select-box">
  <input class="value-holder" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Select a Location">
<div class="advanced-select-button">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<ul class="select-clone custom-list">
  <li data-value="1">Advertising</li>
  <li data-value="2">Airport</li>
  <li data-value="3">Cars</li>
  <li data-value="4">Education</li>
  <li data-value="5">Entertainment</li>
  <li data-value="6">Garden</li>
  <li data-value="2">Airport</li>
  <li data-value="3">Cars</li>
  <li data-value="4">Education</li>
  <li data-value="5">Entertainment</li>
  <li data-value="6">Garden</li>
  <li data-value="2">Airport</li>
  <li data-value="3">Cars</li>
</ul>

<select name="Select_Location" data-placeholder="Select a Location">
   <option>Select Category</option>
          <option value="1">Advertising</option>
          <option value="2">Airport</option>
          <option value="3">Cars</option>
          <option value="4">Education</option>
          <option value="5">Entertainment</option>
          <option value="6">Garden</option>
          <option value="2">Airport</option>
          <option value="3">Cars</option>
          <option value="4">Education</option>
          <option value="5">Entertainment</option>
          <option value="6">Garden</option>
          <option value="2">Airport</option>
          <option value="3">Cars</option>
        </select>
      </span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions guys - but none of these solutions work on the site for some strange reason! Running out of ideas - may have to upload the my development online so you can see my problem

Comment: Have you checked if any error occurs by developer tool on Chrome?

Comment: Yes, no errors at all. However, the code works when I remove the <span class="location select-box"> and </span> tags from the select box. This is the template I am using - http://metrodir.morrise.pl/

Comment: apologies i mean <span class="category select-box">

Comment: I suppose you should remove span tag. Span tag is not permitted to contain input element. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html

Comment: Might just have to do that. Thanks for looking into this though.  It's good to have someone else glance over this and give a second opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your code in [document-ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler.

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

*Example*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your code
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your code
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    alert(this.value);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Select_Location" data-placeholder="Select a Location">
  <option>Select Category</option>
  <option value="1">Advertising</option>
  <option value="2">Airport</option>
  <option value="3">Cars</option>
  <option value="4">Education</option>
  <option value="5">Entertainment</option>
  <option value="6">Garden</option>
  <option value="2">Airport</option>
  <option value="3">Cars</option>
  <option value="4">Education</option>
  <option value="5">Entertainment</option>
  <option value="6">Garden</option>
  <option value="2">Airport</option>
  <option value="3">Cars</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like

```
   $(function() {
      $('select').on('change', function() {
        alert( this.value );
        })
    });
```

Comment: Plus 1 for using the shortcut version of `$(document).ready()`